# Website for mobile phone, unicode problem for nokia

Tags: php, html, unicode, web, nokia

İ have a website for mobile phones (not english)
But i have a problem with nokia (unicode problem)
my website are including php codes
how can i solve this problem with php or html or js ?

Comment: Which Nokia device and/or operating system?  Where is the web site?

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean? What do you expect, and what does the phone display instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the charset in the headers and in the meta tags...

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

And...

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```